# how do you distinguish between shared and static libraries with the same name

Tags: shared-libraries

I have a library that consists of 2 parts.  One is a static 'stub' that links directly into the app (and contains the 'main' function - the app consists of callbacks from there).  The rest of the library modules are contained in a shared library.  This was all set up on AIX, where shared libraries are linked by referencing an 'exports' file.  So the second library didn't follow the normal lib.so naming convention.  The actual name is pulled at link time from the exports file.  So on AIX, the libraries were libemapp.a and shlibemapp.o.  Only libemapp.a is referenced in the makefile - via this variable:

```
LINKEMAPP = -L$(LIBDIR) -lemapp -bI:$(LIBDIR)/shlibemapp.exp
```

Now I'm porting that mess to linux, and need to use a normal lib.so naming convention (I assume) for the shared part.  My first instinct was to use the same name for the static stub and the shared main library.  And I see that there are cases in /usr/lib/... where the same name is used for 2 libraries.  I assume these are really static and shared versions of the same code - not two different libraries.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 103370 May 23  2018 libtic.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     11 May 23  2018 libtic.so -> libtic.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 May 23  2018 libtic.so.5 -> libtic.so.5.9
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  63488 May 23  2018 libtic.so.5.9
```

I can easily use different names, but I'm just wondering.  How do you specify at link time which of the two libraries -ltic pulls in?  And can you override whatever the default choice would be?

And if it's possible, could I have a static libemapp.a and a shared libemapp.so, and link them both to an app.  Probably not, huh?

Comment: Well, you don't have to use `-L` and `-l` when linking; instead you can use explicit filenames, e.g. `gcc ${LDFLAGS} -o main main.o ... /usr/local/lib/libemapp.a /usr/local/lib/libemapp.so` Still, you should invent different names, because the current state is very confusing both for humans and programs (eg `libtool`)

Answer (score 1):

> How do you specify at link time which of the two libraries -ltic pulls in?

(when `libtic.a` and `libtic.so` are in the same linker search directory).

By default, the [GNU binutils linker `ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/)
obeys the option `-ltic` by searching, first in the directories specified by
`-Ldir` in their commandline order, and then in its default search directories in
their configured order, for either of the files `libtic.so` (a shared library) or `libtic.a`
(a static library). The first one that it finds is chosen and input to the linkage, unless both of them are found
in the same search directory, in which case `libtic.so` is chosen.

> And can you override whatever the default choice would be?

Yes. There are three possible ways:-

**1**

If the linker is invoked in the usual way, via one of the GCC frontends (`gcc`,
`g++`, `gfortran`, etc.) then you can pass the option `-static` to the frontend. This will direct it to insert the option `-static` (a.k.a. `-Bstatic`) into the
the commandline that it generates for
`ld` before any of the input files. The linker will obey `-(static|Bstatic)` by ignoring shared libraries
subsequently discovered by library search, until and unless it consumes a
countervailing `-Bdynamic` option. So:

```
gcc ... -static -ltic ...
```

will force `libtic.a` to be preferred to `libtic.so`, and likewise for every `-lname` option in the linkage (including defaults silently appended by the frontend, not just those that you specify)

**2**

Any options `opt0[,...,optN]` for `ld` can be passed through to the linkage via
a GCC frontend with the `-Wl` option, which has the usage;

```
-Wl,opt0[,...,optN]
```

So:

```
gcc ... Wl,-Bstatic -ltic ...
```

is equivalent to the illustration in **1** (provided that the trailing ... portion of the command does not contain `Wl,-Bdynamic`).

**3**

The `ld` option `-l:name` is a variant of the `-lname` that is likewise accepted
by a GCC frontend and passed through to the linkage unchanged. `-l:name` directs
the linker to search in each directory for a file with the *exact* name `name`. So

```
gcc ... -l:libtic.a ...
```

will cause `libtic.a` to be input in preference to `libtic.so`, even if the latter
exists in the same directory and is eligible for linkage. However,

```
gcc ... -static -l:libtic.so
```

will cause the linkage error:

```
attempted static link of dynamic object `./libtic.so'
```

even if `libtic.so` is found, because `-Bstatic` is in effect when `-l:libtic.so`
is considered.

Besides those three variations on the `-l` option, of course you can simply
specify an aribitary `[path/]name` as a linkage argument and the linker will attempt to
to resolve `[path/]name` to an absolute filename and input that file, provided
it does not resolve to a shared library while `-Bstatic` is in effect.

> Could I have a static libemapp.a and a shared libemapp.so, and link them both to an app.

Yes. The linker considers each `-l` option afresh each time it occurs.

```
gcc ... -ltic ... -ltic ......
```

is simply an instance of:

```
gcc ... -lx ... -ly ......
```

and may well result in a different linkage from:

```
gcc ... -ltic ......
```

even if `-ltic` is resolved to the same file every time, because the set of undefined
references that the linker attempts to resolve to definitions provided
by a library may well be a different set of undefined references when the same library
is considered at different points in the linkage.

But `-ltic` need not need resolve to the same file every time. So, provided that both
`libtic.a` and `libtic.so` exist where the linker will find them, whether
in the same search directory or not:

```
gcc -o prog .... -Wl,-Bstatic -ltic ... -Wl,-Bdynamic -ltic
```

will result in `libtic.a` being input to the linkage first, and then `libtic.so`.

The effect of such a linkage will be:

- Symbols to which there are unresolved references in the program when
  `-ltic` is first seen will be statically bound, where possible, to definitions
  provided by object files archived in `libtic.a`<sup>1</sup>.
- After that, there will remain 0 or more symbols that have unresolved
  references in the program when `-ltic` is seen for the second them. Those
  unresolved symbols will be dynamically bound, where possible, to definitions
  provided by `libtic.so`<sup>2</sup>. The linker will not review or revise any static or dynamic bindings it has already made.

Obviously it could be *useful* to link `libtic.a` and then `libtic.so`,
or vice versa, if they were *not* respectively static and dynamic versions of the same library
and specifically, the set of global symbols defined by `libtic.a`
was different from the set of dynamic symbols defined by `libtic.so`. But
obviously too it would be perverse to call them both `libtic.?` when they
do not even have the same API.

Conceivably it might also be useful to link both static and dynamic versions
of the same `tic` library, e.g in a linkage of the form:

```
gcc -o prog main.o ... -Wl,-Bstatic -ltic ... -Wl,-Bdynamic -lfoo -ltic
```

Suppose in a case like this that `x` is a symbol defined by `libtic` to
which an unresolved reference is made in `main.o` and that within `libtic.a`
it is defined in the member `libtic.a(x.o)`.  Then `libtic.a(x.o)` will be
merged into `prog` and references to `x` will be statically bound to that
definition. And suppose that this definition introduces new references to
symbols defined in the shared library `libfoo.so`, and that some of *those*
definitions in turn introduce new references that are defined in `libtic`.

Then the linkage will result in all references to `libtic` that accrue
before `-Wl,-Bstatic` being statically resolved from object files
`libtic.a(x.o), libtic.a(y.o)...` while all further ones that accrue after
`-Wl,-Bdynamic` are dynamically resolved in `libtic.so`. The linkage will be the same as:

```
gcc -o prog main.o ... x.o y.o... -lfoo -ltic
```

It's not beyond the bounds of possibility that you will someday meet with
a linkage scenario that suggests linking both `libtic.a` and `libtic.so` in
that way. But I doubt it, and even if you do, you should favour any reasonable
alternative that is less contrary to normal practice.

---

[1] The object files that provide
those definitions, and no others, will be extracted from `libtic.a` and
physically merged into the program, exactly as if just those object files
were individually named in the linkage command instead of `-ltic`

[2]
The program will be annotated with those
dynamic bindings, enabling the runtime loader to load `libtic.so` into
the program's process and patch the dynamic references with the runtime addresses of
their definitions.